# Converting plt.show to OpenCV imshow function

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

This is the code snippet I am currently working on.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/nvidia/TensorFlowTX2/Faster-RCNN_TF/data/demo/vid.mp4')

while (cap.isOpened()):
    frame = cap # get current frame
    frameId = cap.get(1)
    (grabbed, f) = cap.read()

    #if grabbed == True:
    if(0==0):
        demo(sess, net, f)
        plt.show()
```

The output displayed works framewise. I want to create a live video of the output.

I am interested in converting `plt.show`(matplotlib function) to `imshow`(OpenCV function) so that I can work on continous output video processing.

Thanks

Comment: `cv2.imshow("frame", f);cv2.waitKey(30)`

Comment: When doing tuple restructuring you shouldn't add parens. `grabbed, f = cap.read`. You also shouldn't add parens to ifs: `if  0 == 0:`.

Comment: The demo function returns object detected with bounding boxes which is in the form of plt.show() . When I use cv2.imshow("frame", f);cv2.waitKey(30) . The output obtained is just the live video without any detections or bounding boxes. Hence I want to convert plt.show to an openCV function so that the bounding boxes and objects detected are also displayed.

Comment: The demo(sess,net,f) function ends and returns with the part below. 
    plt.axis('off');
    plt.tight_layout();
    plt.draw();                       How to obtain cv2.imshow from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to convert matplotlib plt.show to openCV imshow function using the below links:
http://www.icare.univ-lille1.fr/tutorials/convert_a_matplotlib_figure

[Convert image from PIL to openCV format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134892/convert-image-from-pil-to-opencv-format)

Comment: please fix your links they don't seem to be working