# Scale contours up/grow outward

Tags: python, opencv, scale, contour

I have a small script <sup>[(GitHub)](https://github.com/akinuri/dump/blob/master/python/opencv/scale-contours/show_contours.py)</sup> (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48399309/2202732)) to detect objects on a white background. The script is working fine and detects the objects. For example, this image:

[image: original image]

becomes this:

[image: contours on image]

and I crop the `boundingRect` (red one).

I'll be doing further operations on this image. For example instead of a rectangle crop, I will be cropping just the contour. (Anyway, these are further problems to be faced.)

What I want to do, now, is scale up/grow the contour (green one). I'm not sure if scale and grow means the same thing in this context, because when I think of scale, there's usually a single point of origin/anchor point. With grow, it's relative to the edges. I want to have something like this (created in Photoshop):

[image: grow example]

So after I detect the object/find contours, I want to grow it by some value/ratio, so that I have some space/pixels to modify which won't affect the object. How can I do that?

Mentioned script:

```
# drop an image on this script file
img_path = Path(sys.argv[1])

# open image with Pillow and convert it to RGB if the image is CMYK
img = Image.open(str(img_path))
if img.mode == "CMYK":
    img = ImageCms.profileToProfile(img, "Color Profiles\\USWebCoatedSWOP.icc", "Color Profiles\\sRGB_Color_Space_Profile.icm", outputMode="RGB")

img      = cv2.cvtColor(numpy.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
gray     = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
kernel   = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
morphed  = cv2.morphologyEx(threshed, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
contours = cv2.findContours(morphed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
contour  = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)[-1]

x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

final = cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 2)
cv2.rectangle(final, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 2)

cv2.imshow("final", final)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

<sub>Images posted here are scaled down to keep the question short. Original images and the script(s) can be found on the mentioned (first paragraph) GitHub page.</sub>

Comment: A naive approach could be: Draw your found contour on some black image (filled, white color). Then use morphological dilation on that "mask", and re-find the now larger contour. Depending on how large your images are, and how fast/efficient this step has to be done, this might be an easy way in terms of programming.

Comment: @HansHirse Would you like to post an answer with some example code? I managed to make it work, and I'll post it if you won't.

Comment: Feel free to post your solution! :) I just gave an idea, no (complete) answer. Glad it worked for you!

Comment: @HansHirse Yep. I'm relatively new to Python, and totally new to OpenCV. So this was a win :)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to HansHirse's suggestion (using morphological dilation), I've managed to make it work.

```
img_path = Path(sys.argv[1])

def cmyk_to_rgb(cmyk_img):
    img = Image.open(cmyk_img)
    if img.mode == "CMYK":
        img = ImageCms.profileToProfile(img, "Color Profiles\\USWebCoatedSWOP.icc", "Color Profiles\\sRGB_Color_Space_Profile.icm", outputMode="RGB")
    return cv2.cvtColor(numpy.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

def cv_threshold(img, thresh=128, maxval=255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY):
    if len(img.shape) == 3:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    threshed = cv2.threshold(img, thresh, maxval, type)[1]
    return threshed

def find_contours(img, to_gray=None):
    kernel   = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
    morphed  = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    contours = cv2.findContours(morphed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    return contours[-2]

def mask_from_contours(ref_img, contours):
    mask = numpy.zeros(ref_img.shape, numpy.uint8)
    mask = cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, (255,255,255), -1)
    return cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

def dilate_mask(mask, kernel_size=10):
    kernel  = numpy.ones((kernel_size,kernel_size), numpy.uint8)
    dilated = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=1)
    return dilated

def draw_contours(src_img, contours):
    canvas = cv2.drawContours(src_img.copy(), contours, -1, (0,255,0), 2)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[-1])
    cv2.rectangle(canvas, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 2)
    return canvas

orig_img      = cmyk_to_rgb(str(img_path))
orig_threshed = cv_threshold(orig_img, 240, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
orig_contours = find_contours(orig_threshed)
orig_mask     = mask_from_contours(orig_img, orig_contours)
orig_output   = draw_contours(orig_img, orig_contours)

dilated_mask     = dilate_mask(orig_mask, 50)
dilated_contours = find_contours(dilated_mask)
dilated_output   = draw_contours(orig_img, dilated_contours)

cv2.imshow("orig_output", orig_output)
cv2.imshow("dilated_output", dilated_output)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I believe the code is self-explonatory enough. An example output:

[image: outputs]

Full script (again) can be found at [show_dilated_contours.py](https://github.com/akinuri/dump/blob/master/python/opencv/scale-contours/show_dilated_contours.py)

**Update**
As a bonus, later I wanted to smooth the contours. I've came across this [blog post](https://pscs5.tumblr.com/post/60284570543) in which the author talks about how to smooth the edges of a shape (in Photoshop). The idea is really simple and can also be applied in OpenCV to smooth the contours. The steps are:

1. Create a mask from contours (or from the shape)
2. Blur the mask
3. Threshold the blurred mask (now, we have a smoother mask than the mask in step 1)
4. Find the contours again on the blurred + thresholded image. Since the mask/shape is smoother, we'll get smoother contours.

Example code and output:

```
# ... continuing previos code

# pass 1
smooth_mask_blurred   = cv2.GaussianBlur(dilated_mask, (21,21), 0)
smooth_mask_threshed1 = cv_threshold(smooth_mask_blurred)

# pass 2
smooth_mask_blurred   = cv2.GaussianBlur(smooth_mask_threshed1, (21,21), 0)
smooth_mask_threshed2 = cv_threshold(smooth_mask_blurred)

# find contours from smoothened mask
smooth_mask_contours = find_contours(smooth_mask_threshed2)
# draw the contours on the original image
smooth_mask_output   = draw_contours(orig_img, smooth_mask_contours)

cv2.imshow("dilated_output", dilated_output)
cv2.imshow("smooth_mask_output", smooth_mask_output)
```

[image: smoother output]

Full code at [show_smooth_contours.py](https://github.com/akinuri/dump/blob/master/python/opencv/scale-contours/show_smooth_contours.py).

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks, really appreciate sharing your own answer and great detail.  This was very informative.