# IndexError: tuple index out of range cv2 using a url

Tags: python, opencv, url

I'm trying to locate the facial land marks of an image using openCV by getting the image using a URL, The code bellow gets the image using the url and converts it from a image to a list and then from a list to a string as before  did this I got the error 'TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, list found',

I am currently getting:

> Blockquote
>   : Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\matth\Desktop\testmctest.py", line 52, in 
>      cv2.imshow('Result',annotate_landmarks(im,get_landmarks(im)))
>    File "C:\Users\matth\Desktop\testmctest.py", line 31, in get_landmarks
>      x,y,w,h =rects[0]
>   IndexError: tuple index out of range

```
def get_landmarks(im):
rects = cascade.detectMultiScale(im, 1.3,5)
x,y,w,h =rects[0]
rect=dlib.rectangle(x,y,x+w,y+h)
return numpy.matrix([[p.x, p.y] for p in predictor(im, rect).parts()])

def annotate_landmarks(im, landmarks):
im = im.copy()
for idx, point in enumerate(landmarks):
    pos = (point[0, 0], point[0, 1])
    cv2.putText(im, str(idx), pos,
                fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX,
                fontScale=0.4,
                color=(0, 0, 255))
    cv2.circle(im, pos, 3, color=(0, 255, 255))
return im



URL = "http://static-23.sinclairstoryline.com/resources/media/d368a1cb-f6af-4a04-83d0-ebc66e984ab2-large16x9_BIOPIC.jpg?1456517822862"

from PIL import Image
import urllib2
im = Image.open(urllib2.urlopen(URL))
o = str(im)
img =[unicode(o, encoding="UTF-8")]
string = ''.join(map(str, img))

im=cv2.imread(string)
cv2.imshow('Result',annotate_landmarks(im,get_landmarks(im)))
```

Comment: Not sure how we can help without seeing the code for `get_landmarks()`.

Comment: @JohnGordon added get_landmarks

Comment: @JohnGordon i realised that i never changed im to string in my code but now ive got a problem where it is stating

Comment: TypeError: image is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Comment: `cascade.detectMultiScale()` is returning an empty tuple, therefore `rects[0]` does not exist.

Comment: ... cv2.imread( ) only receives a filename path... you are passing an image as a string.... take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134892/convert-image-from-pil-to-opencv-format) to see how to convert from PIL images to OpenCV