# JPEG files loaded with Pillow and OpenCV are different. Is this a problem for live image processing?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, neural-network, python-imaging-library, nvidia-digits

I used NVIDIA DIGITS to train an image classifier. The training images are in JPG format. DIGITS uses Pillow to load images.

I noticed that, at inference time, there are relevant differences in accuracy if the JPG images are loaded with OpenCV instead of Pillow. I think that this is related to the different JPEG decoding. Now, since my classifier is going to be used on a live app where images are captured with openCV from a webcam, I would like to know if this difference could be a problem and, if so, how can I overcome it.

EDIT: I know that Pillow uses the RGB format and OpenCV uses the BGR format but the difference is not related to this because I convert the images before making the comparison. The network is trained on BGR images.

Comment: Pillow loads images in RGB, OpenCV in BGR. This can be easily converted like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134892/convert-image-from-pil-to-opencv-format

Comment: I know, I implied that I made the conversion before comparing the images. I'm going to specify it