# Getting an "integer is required (got type tuple)" error, drawing a rectangle using cv2

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have written a basic Python code to create an image and then putting a rectangle on the boundaries. This doesn't seem to work. I have checked multiple sites and this is the exact code they use. Don't know what is the issue.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = Image.new('RGB', (800, 900), color= (171, 183, 255))
cv2.rectangle(img,(1,1),(800,900),(255,0,0),15)
img
```

I am getting this error

```
TypeError
<ipython-input-251-4b78f75077e8> in <module>()
      4 img = Image.new('RGB', (800, 900), color= (171, 183, 255))
      5 # cv2.rectangle(img, 0, 0, 800, 900, (255,0,0))
----> 6 cv2.rectangle(img,(1,1),(800,900),(255,0,0),15)
      7 img

TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: also, what type of object is `Image`? Is that the `Image` module from PIL / Pillow, e.g. `from PIL import Image`?

Comment: Yes, the image module is from Pillow.

Comment: Then [convert that image to a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134892/convert-image-from-pil-to-opencv-format), OpenCV doesn't appear to work directly with PIL images.

Answer (score 4):

The `cv2` module works with *numpy arrays* as images, not with `PIL` `Image` instances.

Because both the `cv2.rectangle` implementation and the `Image` type are implemented entirely in compiled code, the traceback is not all that helpful in understanding what is going wrong. Under the hood, the native `cv2.rectangle()` code tries to access something on the image object that required an integer but `cv2.rectangle()` passed in a tuple instead, as it was expecting to be interacting with a numpy array.

If all you wanted was a blank image with uniform RGB colour, create a numpy array with shape (width, height, 3) and your 3 bands set to your preferred RGB value:

```
import numpy as np

# numpy equivalent of Image.new('RGB', (800, 900), color=(171, 183, 255))
img = np.zeros((800, 900, 3), np.uint8)
img[..., :] = (171, 183, 255)
```

then apply your `cv2.rectangle()` call to that array.

You can always convert from and to a PIL image with:

```
# create numpy array from PIL image
nparray = np.array(img)
# create PIL image from numpy array
img = Image.fromarray(nparray)
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution. Thanks @Martijn Pieters

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.new('RGB', (800, 900), color= (171, 183, 255))
open_cv_image = np.array(img) 

cv2.rectangle(open_cv_image,(0,0),(800,900),(0,0,0),30)
img2 = Image.fromarray(open_cv_image, 'RGB')
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases OpenCV will need wrapping image with UMat class.

```
img = Image.new('RGB', (800, 900), color= (171, 183, 255))
open_cv_image = np.array(img) 
image = cv2.UMat(open_cv_image).get()
cv2.rectangle(open_cv_image,(0,0),(800,900),(0,0,0),30)
```