# Load svg image in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, svg, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to download an svg image and open it in [opencv](https://opencv.org/) for further processing. What I am doing is to convert from svg to png format with [cairosvg](https://cairosvg.org/), open it using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html) and finally convert to `opencv`. The problem here is that the image converted in `opencv` does not look exactly the same as the one in `PIL` format.

```py
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np
import requests
from PIL import Image
from cairosvg import svg2png
import cv2

svg_url = 'https://logincdn.msauth.net/16.000.28611.4/content/images/microsoft_logo_ee5c8d9fb6248c938fd0dc19370e90bd.svg'

# Get svg data
svg_data = requests.get(svg_url).content

# Convert from svg to png
png = svg2png(bytestring=svg_data)

# Open png in PIL
pil_img = Image.open(BytesIO(png))
pil_img.show()  # This looks good

# Convert to opencv
cv_img = np.array(pil_img.convert('RGB'))[:, :, ::-1].copy()  # Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134892/convert-image-from-pil-to-opencv-format
cv2.imshow('cv_img', cv_img)  # This does not look right
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

These are the resulting images from `PIL` and `opencv` format respectively:

[image]

[image]

The `opencv` image does not look right, e.g. the text does not have space between characters.
Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: When you do `convert('RGB')` you discard the alpha/transparency channel which appears to be present in the original image. That's inadvisable. Also `cv2.imshow()` ignores the alpha channel, which helps you even less.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested, you have to preserve alpha channel.

```py
import numpy as np
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from cairosvg import svg2png
import cv2

svg_url = 'https://logincdn.msauth.net/16.000.28611.4/content/images/microsoft_logo_ee5c8d9fb6248c938fd0dc19370e90bd.svg'

svg_data = requests.get(svg_url).content

png = svg2png(bytestring=svg_data)

pil_img = Image.open(BytesIO(png)).convert('RGBA')
pil_img.save('output/pil.png')

cv_img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pil_img), cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)
cv2.imwrite('cv.png', cv_img)
```