# How do I read an image given its link using OpenCV and then plot it using plt.imshow()?

Tags: python-imaging-library, opencv, python

I've tried this

```
from PIL import Image
import requests

im = Image.open(requests.get('http://images.cocodataset.org/train2017/000000000086.jpg', stream=True).raw)
img = cv.imread('im.jpg')
print(img)
```

> This works but print(img) prints "None". Also, shouldn't it be
> cv.imread(im)(doing that gives an error).

when i do

```
plt.imshow(img)
```

it gives an error

> Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float

Comment: `img = np.array(im)`. You need `import numpy as np` beforehand though.

Comment: yes,seems the case. I didn't know that it has to be done. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I would introduce **PIL** as an additional dependency as well as **OpenCV**, nor would I write the image to disk.

I think it would be more direct to do:

```
import cv2
import requests
import numpy as np

# Fetch JPEG data
d = requests.get('http://images.cocodataset.org/train2017/000000000086.jpg')

# Decode in-memory, compressed JPEG into Numpy array
im = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(d.content,np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to save the downloaded image image file to disk before reading it.

```py
from PIL import Image
import requests
import cv2 as cv

im = Image.open(requests.get('http://images.cocodataset.org/train2017/000000000086.jpg', stream=True).raw)

im.save('im.jpg') # write image file to disk

img = cv.imread('im.jpg') # read image file from disk
print(img)
```

If you want to show image directly, without saving it to disk, use [this approach from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14140796/4649452):

```
import numpy as np

im = Image.open(...)
img = np.array(im) 
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # Convert RGB to BGR 
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```