# Python convert JPEG bytes to image array

Tags: python, arrays, image, opencv, python-requests

How can i pass row jpg data to OpenCV? i have the code that saves the image and then opens it again but it is to slow for my purpes, does someone know how to do it without saving?

```py
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO 
import cv2

while True:
    response = requests.get("https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/minion.jpg", stream=True, allow_redirects=True)
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    image.save(r'C:\Users\marti\Pictures\Desktop\scripts\CAM\IMG.jpg', 'JPEG')    #SAVE
    frame = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\marti\Pictures\Desktop\scripts\CAM\IMG.jpg')    #OPEN    
    cv2.imshow("dfsdf",frame)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Comment: Don't use PIL and OpenCV unnecessarily at the same time... you'll confuse yourself. You have a JPEG-encoded image already in `response.content`. Let OpenCV's `imdecode()` read from that. Have a read here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/66853311/2836621

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your initial question, you could do

```py
import requests
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np

url = "https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/minion.jpg"
frame =  Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True, allow_redirects=True).raw)
cv2.imshow("dfsdf", np.asarray(frame)[:,:,::-1])
```

But as per Mark's comment and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66853311/6352677), you can skip PIL altogether:

```py
import requests
import cv2
import numpy as np

url = "https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/minion.jpg"

# Fetch JPEG data
d = requests.get(url)
# Decode in-memory, compressed JPEG into Numpy array
frame = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(d.content,np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv2.imshow("dfsdf",frame)
```

Comment: this answer contains faulty code. `cv2.imshow` will not accept PIL Images. it only accepts numpy arrays. -- pass `np.asarray(frame)` instead... but be prepared to see strange colors because PIL uses RGB order while OpenCV expects BGR order, and interprets the data accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophRackwitz, I fixed the code and added the corresponding imports.