# PIL, CV2: Image quality breaks after converting from PIL to Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FAgzPZJrDDQfg1C1tt57CqINoWVTDSBj/view?usp=sharing) image and I read as a PIL file. Then, I save it back using `save` method in PIL and `imwrite` method in `cv2`. Saving the image with `imwrite` downgrades the image quality (it becomes black and white and text can't be read).

```
image = Image.open("image.png")

cv2_image = numpy.asarray(image)

image.save("pil.png")
cv2.imwrite("opencv.png", cv2_image)
```

Here are the output files:

[pil.png](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MgDys59XQQvYRkaT044kH2wgUjLmpLKu/view?usp=sharing)
[opencv.png](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-pa94lF4g4xbWN4oiCKfncTIoU4g8yqV/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134892/convert-image-from-pil-to-opencv-format)? You need to convert the PIL image to an OpenCV image before saving with cv2.imwrite.

Comment: Also, just remembered, I believe PIL and OpenCV have the color channels in different orders - one of them's BGR and the other's RGB. And it might be prudent to check if whether each module takes int values between 0 and 255 or float values between 0 and 1.

Comment: please work on a [mre], including the required input. that code could not have produced the output you show. something more must be going on.

Comment: The PNG file is 8-bit indexed.  I'm guessing cv2 is not copying the palette.

Comment: PIL isn't giving *numpy* the palette.

Answer (score 4):

The input image is a palette image - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621). So, you need to convert it to RGB otherwise you just pass OpenCV the palette indices but without the palette.

So, you need:

```
image = Image.open(...).convert('RGB')
```

Now make it into a Numpy array:

```
cv2image = np.array(image)
```

But that will be in RGB order, so you need to reverse the channel order:

```
cv2image = cv2image[..., ::-1]
```